# Spring Security OAuth2 и анонимные пользователи

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth2

Есть веб приложение на Spring MVC, пытаюсь добавить к нему аутентификацию через Google.
Настраиваю SpringSecurity следующим образом:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client

@PropertySource("classpath:google-oauth2.properties")
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

@Value("${oauth2.clientId}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${oauth2.clientSecret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${oauth2.userAuthorizationUri}")
private String userAuthorizationUri;

@Value("${oauth2.accessTokenUri}")
private String accessTokenUri;

@Value("${oauth2.tokenName:authorization_code}")
private String tokenName;

@Value("${oauth2.scope}")
private String scope;

@Value("${oauth2.userInfoUri}")
private String userInfoUri;

@Value("${oauth2.filterCallbackPath}")
private String oauth2FilterCallbackPath;

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    // May need an OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint for non-browser clients
    return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(oauth2FilterCallbackPath);
   }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContextFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .anonymous().disable();
}

@Bean
public Filter ssoFilter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(oauth2FilterCallbackPath);
    OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
    GoogleUserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new GoogleUserInfoTokenServices(userInfoUri, clientId);
    facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    facebookFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return facebookFilter;    }

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    details.setId("google-oauth-client");
    details.setClientId(clientId);
    details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri(userAuthorizationUri);
    details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
    details.setTokenName(tokenName);
    String commaSeparatedScopes = scope;
    details.setScope(parseScopes(commaSeparatedScopes));
    details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
    details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);

    return details;
}

private List<String> parseScopes(String commaSeparatedScopes) {
    List<String> scopes = new LinkedList<>();
    Collections.addAll(scopes, commaSeparatedScopes.split(","));
    return scopes;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/pages/**");
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new NoopAuthenticationManager();
}

private static class NoopAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "No authentication should be done with this AuthenticationManager");
    }
}

@Bean
@Description("Enables ${...} expressions in the @Value annotations"
        + " on fields of this configuration. Not needed if one is"
        + " already available.")
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

Авторизация через google работает отлично, но из за отключенного анонимного доступа пользователи не могут зайти даже на главную страницу без авторизации.
Если включить анонимный доступ, перестает работать OAuth с ошибкой:

> Authentication Failed: Authentication is required to obtain an
> access token (anonymous not allowed)

Единственное нормальное описание проблемы нашел [на форуме Spring](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/121682-authentication-is-required-to-obtain-an-access-token-anonymous-not-allowed)

Но я не могу понять 1 момента.
В моем сценарии пользователи до авторизации ходят по сайту под анонимной учеткой, а после авторизации через OAuth получают свой профиль и ходят уже под ним. Соответсвтенно, авторизация через OAuth нужна для того что бы сопоставить учетку Google с локальным пользователем и получить часть данных из профиля Google. В варианте описанном на форуме сказано, что до авторизации через OAuth необходимо дать пользователю не анонимную учетку для идентификации пользователя.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой механизм аутентификации. Может я в корне не понимаю предназначение OAuth?